# what's wrong with this subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a subquery to insert data into a table of a database from data gathered from a table of another database.While i run this query i am getting the following error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'SELECT * FROM campaign_traffic_db.campaign_merge WHERE
> adform_clientID = 135456 ' at line 1

```
INSERT
INTO
  135456_1257994024297010.campaign_merge(
    adform_client,
    adform_clientID,
    adform_campaign,
    adform_campaignID,
    adform_campaignStartDate,
    adform_campaignEndDate,
    adform_campaignCurrency,
    adform_cost,
    adform_clicks,
    adform_ctr,
    adform_impression,
    fb_client,
    fb_clientID,
    fb_campaign,
    fb_campaignID,
    fb_campaignStartDate,
    fb_campaignEndDate,
    fb_cost,
    fb_clicks,
    fb_impression,
    created_at,
    updated_at
  )
VALUES (
SELECT
  *
FROM
  campaign_traffic_db.campaign_merge
WHERE
  adform_clientID = '135456' AND fb_clientID = '1257994024297010')
```

Comment: Remove `Values(`. Just `INSERT (..) SELECT .. FROM...;` [Documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: why is that so? i have used subquery with similar syntax before ant that worked?can u explain a bit?

Comment: I sincerely doubt that you have used syntax like `INSERT INTO <table> (..) VALUES (SELECT ... FROM);` before since that's not supported functionality in any RDBMS. Perhaps `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (1,2,(select max(foo) from bar), 4)` or something silly like that may have worked, although I'm not certain it would.

Comment: not working in my case

Comment: I would highly encourage you to not use `SELECT *` in this case. My guess is that it's "not working" because your fields coming from your SELECT don't line up with your fields in your insert list. I'd be happy to help diagnose more but you'll have to share the error message.

Comment: You know you're missing a `)` at the end?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney edited the post.it's all the same though

Comment: What error do you get when you try the solution @JNevill suggested?

Comment: come on, let's not feed the troll, solution is to follow carefully the (very clear) manual instructions on the insert select mysql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up to my comment above, the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO <table> (f1, f2, f3)
VALUES (SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM <table2>);
```

Will not work. You either use `VALUES()` or you supply a `SELECT` statement that returns the desired fields to match your INSERT field list.

```
INSERT INTO 135456_1257994024297010.campaign_merge
(
    adform_client,
    adform_clientID,
    adform_campaign,
    adform_campaignID,
    adform_campaignStartDate,
    adform_campaignEndDate,
    adform_campaignCurrency,
    adform_cost,
    adform_clicks,
    adform_ctr,
    adform_impression,
    fb_client,
    fb_clientID,
    fb_campaign,
    fb_campaignID,
    fb_campaignStartDate,
    fb_campaignEndDate,
    fb_cost,
    fb_clicks,
    fb_impression,
    created_at,
    updated_at
)
SELECT * FROM campaign_traffic_db.campaign_merge
WHERE adform_clientID = '135456' AND fb_clientID = '1257994024297010';
```

Should work, assuming that your fields in `campaign_traffic_db.campaign_merge` line up perfectly with your list of fields in the `INSERT` portion of the statement.

The documentation on INSERT...SELECT can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)